# Oracle to Postgres Operator in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I am new to AIrflow, I am trying to implement oracle to postgres data migration using Airflow. Can anyone suggest me the documentation or operator to deploy the same.

Looking for the documentation and operator to done this activity